# How to include directories in cmake for windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include, cmake, eigen

I am using cmake to compile the library [g2o](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) for visual studio express. I could not set the path to [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) while compiling the code using cmake for visual studio. I am using windows. I tried copying the Eigen directory to the trunk directory. But later found out it is silly as the configuration is set in the cmake files to check for the Eigen include directories.

How can I point to the Eigen include directory while compiling.The findeigen3.cmake file is  [here](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindEigen3.cmake). I understand that I need to change the variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR to the folder where I downloaded the Eigen library. But how can I achieve that?

Comment: Try adding EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=<path-to-eigen-library> in project properties's Debugging->Environment

Comment: @mohitj2007 i tried it but didnt have any effect

Comment: are you getting compilation(header missing) or linking(lib missing) errors?

Comment: @mohitj2007 compilation errors where #include<Eigen/Core> is there in the code

Comment: Check what is the path in "C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories"?

Comment: @user2907250, please clean build directory, launch `CMake` here and add in your question `CMake`'s output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CMake-gui? If so ( and if I'm understanding your question ) you should look for EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR when you're configuring your project. Note, it will be under 'Advanced' because of this line in the find_module "mark_as_advanced(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)". You will see the advanced checkbox near the top, select it. Then just fill in the path. That should take care of setting the proper VS settings in the project file.